# Un UIButton puede tomar la imagen de un UIImage Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Este es mi código.

```
NSArray *sub = [self.view subviews];
if ([sub count] == 0) return;
for (int i=0; i<sub.count; i++){
UIButton *boton = (UIButton *)sub[i];
        //Convierto el boton a UIImage
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(boton.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
        [boton.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage * imageOriginal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        // crear un nuevo tamaño, es decir el tamaño de imagen redimensionado
        CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(boton.frame.size.width, boton.frame.size.height);
        // hacer el recorte final rec basado en los valores calculados
        CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(boton.frame.origin.x, boton.frame.origin.y, boton.frame.size.width, boton.frame.size.height);
        // inicia un nuevo contexto, con el factor de escala 0.0 para que las pantallas retina obtengan una imagen de alta calidad
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, NO, 0.0);
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);
        }
        //Modifica el trazado de recorte actual interceptándolo con el rectángulo especificado
        UIRectClip(clipRect);
        //Dibuja toda la imagen en el rectángulo especificado, escalándola según sea necesario para que se ajuste. Este método dibuja toda la imagen en el contexto gráfico actual, respetando el ajuste de orientación de la imagen. En el sistema de coordenadas por defecto, las imágenes se sitúan abajo ya la derecha del origen del rectángulo especificado. Sin embargo, este método respeta cualquier transformación aplicada al contexto gráfico actual.
        [imageOriginal drawInRect:clipRect];
        //Elimina el contexto de gráficos basado en mapas de bits actual de la parte superior de la pila
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [sub[i] setImage:imageOriginal];
        NSLog(@"ImageButton: %@", boton);
}
```

Lamentablemente truena alguna manera para pasarle la imagen que almaceno en el UIImage al UIIbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré como solucionar el problema.

En general, si no se especifica una propiedad para un estado, el valor predeterminado es utilizar el valor `UIControlStateNorma`l. Si el valor `UIControlStateNormal` no se establece, l**a propiedad predeterminada es un valor de sistema**. Por lo tanto, como mínimo, debe establecer el valor para el estado normal, es decir:

```
[sub[i] setImage:imageOriginal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: JCTimmypage deberias extender un poco la respuesta explicando que tenias mál antes y como lo soluciona esto ahora, para que la respuesta sea útil a otros usuarios con tu mismo problema y no termine cerrada por falta de calidad. Saludos.

Comment: gracias por el consejo

Comment: En general, si no se especifica una propiedad para un estado, el valor predeterminado es utilizar el valor UIControlStateNormal. Si el valor UIControlStateNormal no se establece, la propiedad predeterminada es un valor de sistema. Por lo tanto, como mínimo, debe establecer el valor para el estado normal.

Comment: De nada, como creador de la pregunta tu respuesta es valiosa ya que sabes mejor que nadie si funciona o no. Editala (usa el botón **editar** de debajo de la respuesta), no lo agreges como comentario. He añadido tu comentario a la respuesta por esta vez, si quieres añadir más cosas solo editala, todos los aportes son bienvenidos. Saludos.